# Why does Post work, but not Get, with the same route and args?

Tags: c#, post, controller, get, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following Controller code:

```
namespace PlatypusReports.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/platypus")]
    public class PlatypusController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("{unit}/{begindate}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(string unit, string begindate)
        {
            . . .
        }

        [Route("{unit}/{begindate}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get(string unit, string begindate)
        {
            . . .
        }
        . . .
```

Calling the POST method works, but calling the GET method does not; in the latter case, I get, "405 Method Not Allowed - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

I call them with the same exact URL from Postman:

```
http://localhost:52194/api/platypus/poisontoe/201509
```

...the only difference being I select "POST" it works, and when I select "GET" it doesn't.

Why would POST work but not GET? What do I have to change in my GET code to get it to be supported/allowed?

Comment: when you perform GET, can you use fiddler to capture the request payload? i think you might missing querystring for the two input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an apicontroller you don't need the decorators HttpPost and HttpGet. If you remove them it should then work.

Comment: Right as rain; in fact, you're even righter than purple rain, which is just plain weird. Thanks to goodness, the Purple Reign of Terror seems to be history.